# Apply scipy stats function as a layer in a Keras neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, statistics

I want to apply a scipy stats function as a layer in a Keras neural network, something like this:

```py
from scipy import stats

class BoxCox(layers.Layer):

    def call(self, inputs):
        return stats.boxcox(inputs)

# part of usage in model
x1 = layers.Dense(81)(x)
x1 = BoxCox()(x1)
x1 = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x1)
```

There are issues with the `stats` library functions not accepting tensors. For instance, an error message is

```py
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (activation_12/IdentityN:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Is there any way I can run such a function as a layer in a neural network?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Layer must support backpropagation of gradient. Only tensorflow function supporting it. You can not use other functions.